# InputSystem “Invoke Unity Event” don't respond to input

Tags: unity, c#, input

I was making the Input Systen code for my game.
I was about to test it and I realized that the controls don't respond.

Here is how I've configured my PlayerInput component:

[image: My PlayerInput Component configuration]

And here is how I've set up the Input Action Asset for the Start action:

[image: My Input Action Asset set up]

In the function that refers to the Start action I've set up a Debug message, but it doesn't pop up and my code inside this function doesn't execute.

My StartGame function is:

```cs
    public void StartGame(InputAction.CallbackContext value) {
        Debug.Log("Input Recieved");
        // Game Code Here
    }
```

Someone knows why it isn't responding to input?

Comment: Make sure your ActiveInput Handling is support the new InputSystem.
You can find the corresponding setting in the Player settings (menu: Edit > Project Settings > Player), under Active Input Handling. You can change this setting at any time. Doing so will restart the Editor.

Comment: @Emad Yes, I just checked it, and my Active Input Handling option is set to `Input System Package (New)`